# What is an algebra of continuous functions?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

A question in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds begins by simply stating:

> [2-10] For any topological space $M$; let $C(M)$ denote the algebra of continuous
>   functions $f : M \rightarrow R$...

What is an algebra of continuous functions?

Comment: $C(M)$ is just the set of all continous functions $f:M\to \mathbb R$. Under pointwise multiplication of functions, it's an _algebra_ in the sense defined on page 624. Sorry if my wording wasn't completely clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An algebra is a set which is a vector space but further has a product defined between its elements.

The wikipedia has a nice explanation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field

In your case, you have the product of two continuous functions given by

$fg(x)= (f(x))(g(x))$, which again defines a continuous function

Comment: Sure, but how can I be certain "algebra of continuous functions" means "algebra" in that same sense?

Comment: Because that is a standard construction in differential geometry and that's the way it is used in that book.

Comment: Could you recommend, as part of your answer, a standard reference which defines an algebra of continuous functions? Note that the Wikipedia page you linked does not contain an example of the algebra of continuous functions.

Comment: Maybe it will be more clear if I say it this way: The algebra of continuous functions $C(M)$ used by Lee is just the set of continuous functions equipped with the operations of multiplication by scalars, product and sum defined pointwise. In other words, the algebra of continuous functions is just an algebra (in the sense of the wiki) whose elements happen to be continuous functions.

Comment: @Sak Where are the scalars coming from?

Answer (score 3):

To start, as a set $C(M)$ is the set of all continuous functions $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$.  Now this set has some natural algebraic operations: you can add two continuous functions by adding their values at every point, to get another continuous function.  You can similarly multiply two continuous functions, or multiply a single continuous function by a fixed real number.  Together, these operations make $C(M)$ an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, and this is what is meant by "the algebra of continuous functions".